# c++11 shared pointer performance penalty in a multi threaded environment

Tags: c++11, smart-pointers

How much of a performance hit should we expect by using smart pointers in a program with multiple threads? Are there any reliable benchmarks done on this?

Comment: smart pointers are usually not thread-safe, it's hard to make them lock-less since they contains 2 machine words. therefore you would need a lock. locks usually are not very cpu intensive but they may cause contention. 

Amount of contention depends on your design really.

Comment: I am actually referring to smart pointer implementations that are thread safe such as boost shared_pointer.

Comment: @Roman `std::shared_ptr` is thread-safe with respect to the object being managed (it's OK if one thread copies a `std::shared_ptr` to `x` and another thread destructs a different `std::shared_ptr` to `x` concurrently, for example). I would be surprised if most smart pointers didn't offer such guarantees.

Comment: @Roman: Your comment is wrong on several details.  `std::shared_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr` are precisely the tool wanted for managing the lifetime of objects passed between threads (proactor pattern, libdispatch, thread pools etc.).  Whilst the reference count is non-zero, threads contend only whilst atomically incrementing or decrementing the reference-count.  This typically involves at best a single instruction and at worst a spin-lock and a few memory barriers. Generally this arrangement is said to be 100-200 times cheaper than, say, a kernel mutex.

Comment: Most of the contention is in fact on the front-side bus, and barriers are not cheap either - just how cheap depends on system architecture and degree of parallelism.

On large SMP systems (especially those with a NUMA architecture) `shared_ptr` doesn't scale so well, and you would want to look at lock-less data structures.

Comment: @Roman There is 16B compare-and-swap in x86_64 if the implementation uses contiguous memory for those two words.

Comment: @marko Maybe my knowledge is outdated.
gcc 4.8.1 did not have implementation of atomic_XXX operations on shared_ptr. See https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2013-08/msg00161.

boost:shared_ptr is not c++11 shared pointer

Comment: I would assume they must have fixed that by now to be standards compliant. 

`boost::shared_ptr` is close enough to be practically interchangeable at source level with `std::shared_ptr`.  Boost does have the thread safety guarantee.  If stuck with a broken C++ standard library, boost might be the best option.

Comment: @marko Thanks for the details. Our choice is between raw pointers and smart pointers. Do you know any details about how much of a performance cost we can expect in this case compared to raw pointers. mutex's are out of the question in our application due to low latency requirements.

Comment: This hugely depends on your target architecture to be honest - for instance, the front-side bus and cache architecture.  Whilst some platforms can do this with very few instructions, they possibly hide a pipe-line stall in which you can't get a context switch (or perhaps service an interrupt).  Whether this bothers you rather depends how low-latency your requirements are.   Guess you're going to have to do some measurement.  My guess is that the cost is up to 50-100 times more than a raw pointer, but potentially very little if uncontended.

Comment: @marko Our target architecture is intel. Even when there is no contention, shouldn't there be a penalty due to memory ordering? I've read somewhere that an implementation can use relaxed ordering, but not sure how this will work. I thought increment/decrement has to be totally ordered.